# Dart Initialise Super Constructor in Factory Named Constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I initialise the variables of a super class in a named factory constructor? Here is my sample code:

```
class ClassA{
  final a;
  final b;

  ClassA({this.a, this.b});

}

class ClassB extends ClassA{
  final c;
  List <String> myList;

  ClassB({this.c,this.myList});


  factory ClassB.fromJson(json){
    var list = json["list"] as List;
    List<String> tempList = [];

    list.forEach((item)=>tempList.add(item));
    return ClassB(
      c: json["c"],
      myList: tempList
    );
  }


}
```

I am not sure how or where exactly do i call the super constructor for Class A so that I can initialise its variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the way to call `super`:

```
class ClassA{
  final a;
  final b;

  ClassA({this.a, this.b});

}

class ClassB extends ClassA{
  final c;
  List <String> myList;

  ClassB({final a, final b, this.c,this.myList}) : super(a: a, b: b);

  factory ClassB.fromJson(json){
    var list = json["list"] as List;
    List<String> tempList = [];

    list.forEach((item)=>tempList.add(item));
    return ClassB(
      c: json["c"],
      myList: tempList
    );
  }
}
```